# Seeing (draft of) old question when trying to write a new one

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, asking-questions

I'm trying to ask a question on Stack Overflow. I have already asked two questions today, and I would like to ask a third one. However, when I click "Ask Question" button I get a form in which I see my previous question (as if I want to edit my previous question). Does anybody know why?

Comment: This sounds like the auto-saving of the content to me. Did your previous question post okay?

Comment: Did you actually post the old question? Also, caching.

Comment: Looking at his SO account, he has asked 2 questions 2 hours ago, so it seems he did ask/submit the question.

Comment: Yes, I posted my previous question and got some answers.

Comment: Title is misleading; you **can** post question you just see previous question contents when starting new one. That's whole different thing.

Comment: @Sha Wiz Dow Ard, I see what I do not expect to see and what I do not understand. Of course, I had the idea to delete the content of the form and submit it as a new question but I thought that in this way I can delete my previous question. Since I do not want to risk and I do not want to delete my previous question, I decide not to post the new question. So, I cannot post a new question.

Comment: I ran into this problem too. I even logged out and back in, and the question form is still pre-filled with my last question. I would guess it's a **server-side bug**.

Comment: @Oded, just in case you missed it: at least 3 questions about this have been posted in the last 15 days ([like just now today](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224632/question-retrieved-from-draft)), and someone else commented above too. Sounds like some bug to me.

Comment: @Luke: Yes, drafts are stored on the server; that is by design.

Comment: @Arjan: perhaps a race condition where the draft is saved *after* submitting the question; drafts are saved using AJAX calls I think, so in theory a draft save could be sent at the moment the user submits the question; if the draft save request arrives after the question submit a new draft is created. If the issue is on the rise, the cause could be anything from load balancer changes on the SE side to browser tech changes to network topology updates.

Comment: Very true, @Martijn. To investigate someone who keeps seeing the problem needs to get in touch with the developers. In [comments elsewhere](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169640/stack-overflow-being-forced-to-edit-an-old-question-instead-of-creating-a-new-o?lq=1#comment500884_169640) someone seems to have gotten the problem at least two times. I guess you & I ask too few questions to investigate. ;-)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

What you see is a saved draft copy of your question.

If that's a question you already asked, then just click the 'discard' link next to the `Post Your Question` button, and enter a new question:

[image: discard link]

Comment: Is it a bug that it was still there when the question had been posted though?

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett: Perhaps, but if the OP went back in the browser history and re-posted something, then that could be driver error too.

Comment: Ahh ok, that would make sense. I was thinking that since drafts are stored server side it would be a bug, but I can see how it could now be a user-side issue.

Comment: That's a nice red circle. ;) Which tool did you use?

Comment: @Spontifixus: Hand drawn, actually; I used Skitch.

Comment: I've seen this problem mentioned 4 times in 2 weeks now; I guess @George is right, some bug.