# Stack Overflow: Being forced to edit an old question instead of creating a new one

Tags: bug

I am trying to ask a new question on Stack Overflow, but whenever I click on "Ask Question", the page that opens is that of an old question I'd asked 19 hours ago.... which is like I want to edit. But what I want is to ask a new question.

Is that a bug or is Stack Overflow punishing me for something am not aware of?

Comment: what happens if you go to http://stackoverflow.com/question/ask ?

Comment: @WouterJ - you missed an 's' in questions. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

Comment: It's probably just an old draft... if you're comfortable removing it click the discard link at the bottom.

Comment: @WouterJ if I do so it still takes me back to that question

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards Funny enough, if I click "Ask Question" here in meta it takes me back to editing this same question!? A bug in my profile?

Comment: Caching. Or possibly oscillation.

Comment: @lukik, if you keep seeing the problem then please comment on [Seeing (draft of) old question when trying to write a new one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168456/seeing-draft-of-old-question-when-trying-to-write-a-new-one), and then make sure to include `@Oded`, as he tagged that question as status-bydesign while this clearly seems to be a bug. Success!